# Django model function to save ImageField if none image given = execption

Tags: python, django, save

i have a Django models function to save an image correctly. Currently it seems that Django-SmartFields is buggy at that point, see: https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields/issues/17 and sorl is not working properly, no idea why.
So i quickly have written down this:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content", max_length=5000)
    tag = models.CharField(verbose_name="Tags/Meta - (sep. by comma)", max_length=50, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    postattachment = fields.FileField(
        verbose_name="Attachment",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=get_file_path_user_uploads,
        validators=[file_extension_postattachment, file_size_postattachment]
    )
    postcover = fields.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Cover",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=get_file_path_user_uploads,
        validators=[default_image_size, default_image_file_extension]
    )
    up_vote = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Post Up-Vote(s)', default=0)
    down_vote = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Post Down-Vote(s)', default=0)
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        imageTemproary = Image.open(self.postcover)
        outputIoStream = BytesIO()
        imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize((700, 525))
        imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='JPEG', quality=85)
        outputIoStream.seek(0)
        self.postcover = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.jpeg" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But if i now want to clear the Picture trough my form i get the following error:

> The 'postcover' attribute has no file associated with it.

full trace:

```
 Internal Server Error: /post/1/edit/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
   File "/app/app_Accounts/decorators.py", line 33, in _wrapped_view
     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ratelimit/decorators.py", line 30, in _wrapped
     return fn(*args, **kw)
   File "/app/app/views.py", line 473, in post_edit
     post.save()
   File "/app/app/models.py", line 173, in save
     imageTemproary = Image.open(self.postcover)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2638, in open
     fp.seek(0)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 20, in <lambda>
     seek = property(lambda self: self.file.seek)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 41, in _get_file
     self._require_file()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 38, in _require_file
     raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'postcover' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Does smb. has a quick workaround on that behaviour?

Thx in advance

Comment: Please show your full stacktrace of error and whole content of models.py

Comment: I just updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why cant you check if image exists

```
import os //added
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
     if self.postcover:
         if os.path.exists(self.postcover.path):     //this was added
            imageTemproary = Image.open(self.postcover)
            outputIoStream = BytesIO()
            imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize((700, 525))
            imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='JPEG', quality=85)
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            self.postcover = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.jpeg" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
     super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @Venom sorry what? just replace the model save with the above

Comment: Well i did ;) But nothing changed. I'm able to save a new image onto the field but im not able to clear the data of it... So im still at the same point as before... Sorry for that misunderstanding in first place. thx so far.

Comment: Okay that again helped somehow, im able to save the field but the image does not get resized or converted to jpeg. Now it reacts like i would not use your lines at all... Just like the Django Build-In flow

Comment: seems that if os.path.exists(self.postcover.url) <url> is not reachable

Comment: @Venom its not url its path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190992/discussion-between-venom-and-jibin-mathews).